# How to properly remove PropertyChanged.Fody via NuGet

Tags: nuget, fody, fody-propertychanged

I intended to use Fody.PropertyChanged in one of my projects, and it was properly added via NuGet:

```
Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody
```

I realized, it was in the wrong project, so I used the uninstall command:

```
Uninstall-Package PropertyChanged.Fody
```

After that I added it to the proper project.

Now, when I try to build my solution, I get the following error in the *initial project* that shouldn't have Fody installed:

> Fody: You don't seem to have configured any weavers. Try adding a Fody
>   nuget package to your project. Have a look here
>   http://nuget.org/packages?q=fody for the list of available packages.

There is no reference to Fody in the project, I deleted the Fody reference from the `packages.config` file and there is no XML file.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to also

```
Uninstall-Package Fody
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove The "FodyWeavers.xml"  and Open the Project file with NotePad or notePad++ and remove the following lines

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports"  BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<Import Project="..\packages\Fody.1.29.2\build\portable-net+sl+win+wpa+wp\Fody.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Fody.1.29.2\build\portable-net+sl+win+wpa+wp\Fody.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've recently updated the Fody library? When it asked to replace the existing "FodyWeavers.xml" you might have permitted it to do so. If you have a backup of the project, get the "FodyWeavers.xml" from that and replace it with the new one. Clean and Rebuild the solution.

Comment: I did not update it. The Fody library should not be there at all. Seemingly it is not there but the project contains some hidden reference to it.

Comment: Are you using the PropertyChanged.Fody library?

Comment: Read the initial post. In one of the projects I use, in the other I don't want to, yet it complains about it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically address the project you don't want Fody in, but sometimes VS gives vague/odd errors.

I just went through a similar issue after installing `PropertyChanged.Fody` for the first time, and couldn't build as soon as I included and referenced it... I wonder if any of these details from my experience might help (making sure these points exist in the project you want the lib in).

1. Make sure you have the following references in your `packages.config` from when you ran `Install-Package PropertyChanged.Fody`:

```xml
<package id="Fody" version="1.24.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" /> 
<package id="PropertyChanged.Fody" version="1.49.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
```

2. Make sure there is `FodyWeavers.xml` in the top level of the project you want to use it in.
3. `FodyWeavers.xml` should look like this (I had to add `<PropertyChanged />` to mine)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged />
</Weavers>
```